# Maximize the sum of product of adjacent numbers

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

Here is a question that I encountered during an [Interviewstreet](http://interviewstreet.com) [codesprint](https://zulily.interviewstreet.com/).
I was unable to find a a solution or even think in its direction. I'd be thankful if someone could help me find the soultion, or explain me how the problem neeeds to be dealt with.

> Given numbers 1, 2, 3, .., N,  arrange them in a order such that the
>   sum of product of adjecent numbers is maximized.
>
> For example: if N = 3, and we order them as ( 1, 2, 3 ), the sum of
>   products is 1*2 + 2*3  = 8 and if we order them as ( 1, 3 ,2 ) the sum
>   of products is 1*3 + 3*2 = 9.
>
> **Input format :**
>
> First line of the input contains T, the number of test-cases. Then
>   follow T lines, each containing an integer N.
>
> **Output format :**
>
> For each test case print the maximum sum of product of adjacent
>   numbers.
>
> **Sample input :**
>
> 2 2 4
>
> **Sample output :**
>
> 2 23
>
> **Explanation :**
>
> In first test case given permutation is ( 1, 2 ). So maximum sum of
>   product is 1*2. In Second test case the numbers are (1,2,3,4).
>   Arrangement 1,3,4,2 has sum of product of adjacent numbers as
>   1*3+3*4+4*2 = 23. No other arrange has sum of product of adjacent
>   numbers more than 23.
>
> **Constraints :**
>
> 1 <= T <= 10 1 <= N <= 200000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximum sum-of-adjacent-products comes when the largest value is in the middle of the sequence, and the successively lower values alternate to its left and right. That is, your sequence for a given value n would be [..., n-3, n-1, n, n-2, n-4, ...] (or the reverse of this, which will have the same sum of products).

So, leaving out the input-parsing bits, here's the heart of the algorithm (in Python, but easily translated to other languages):

```
def maximumSumOfAdjacentProducts(n):
    if n == 1: # special case needed for a one element sequence
        return 1

    sumOfProducts = n * (n-1) # this pair is the "center" of the sequence

    for i in range(n-2, 0, -1): # iterate downward from n-2 to 1
        sumOfProducts += i*(i+2) # each adjacent pair is separated by 2

    return sumOfProducts
```

Comment: Assuming this is true (which seems to be the case, the answer for odd n is equal to k*(8k^2+18k+1)/3, where n = 2k+1. A similar formula is available for even n.

Comment: And for even n, it's (2k-1)(4k^2+5k-3)/3, where n=2k.

Comment: Yeah, I was just staring on working that out too. I think you can prove that this sort of sequence is the best possible by induction. With the trivial length 2 sequence as the base case, you'd always want to add a new largest element in between the largest pair of values, which by induction, will always be at the center. The new sequence of length N will be larger than the previous sequence of length N-1 by `N*(N-1) + N*(N-2) - (N-1)*(N-2)` which simplifies to `N^2-3`.

Comment: Does this work in general? Say if we instead have n real numbers greater than 0. I think one need to prove if x>a>b>c>d, then (a+b)x-ab > (c+d)x-cd

Comment: oh yes it does. It's not hard to prove.

Answer (score 2):

1. Sort the array, call it `sortedArray` in ascending order.
2. Remove `max1`, `max2` and put them in a `result` list.
3. Remove the next element and add it to the side of `MAX(max1, max2)`.
4. Update `max1` and `max2`. i.e. `max1` is left side and `max2` is right side of the list.
5. Repeat steps 3 & 4 until the sorted input array has elements.

**Example:**

```
inputArray: 1,3,4,2,5

sortedArray: 1,2,3,4,5

Add 5 and 4 to the list first.

result = [5, 4]

Remove 3 and add it to MAX(5,4)

result = [3, 5, 4]

Remove 2 and add it to MAX(3,4)

result = [3, 5, 4, 2]

Remove 1 and add it to MAX(3,2)

result = [1, 3, 5, 4, 2]
```

Comment: There's no need to sort the array, as it's always (1, 2, ..., N).

Comment: @ffa0 I thought the initial array is unsorted. If it's always (1,2,..., N) then the step 1 can be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

This is [OEIS A101986](https://oeis.org/A101986), and can be solved in constant time.

a(n) = n*(2*n^2 + 9*n + 1)/6.